# Why does creating Media Player object crash my android code?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, accelerometer

I'm creating a little program that plays the mario jump sound when someone jumps.
I can use the Z acceleration to make the program display a message when it reaches a certain value like 10 m/s^2. I want it to play a sound from a media player object, but when I even create the media player object, it crashes the code. I'll post the code on pastebin.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
        Sensor accelerometer;
        SensorManager sm;
        TextView acceleration;
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.jump); //Line 17


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                sm= (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
                accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);           
                acceleration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acceleration);             

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
                acceleration.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] +  "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);
                if (event.values[2] > 10.8 ) {
                        acceleration.setText("Z IS REALLY BIG!!");
                }
        }

}
```

The addition of line 17 is what crashed the program...

Answer (score 1):

You need to split

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.jump);
```

into two parts as follows:

```
MediaPlayer mp; //keep this where the current line is
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.jump); //Put this in onCreate()
```

Your app crashed because you were initializing `mp` outside of a method body, which meant it was executed before `onCreate()`. As your Activity object is not ready until `onCreate()` has been called, calling `getBaseContext()` results in a `NullPointerException`.